# Android NDK: "fatal error: 'thread' file not found"

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk

I am trying to compile a NDK only app (command line app).
I was using C++11 for many things, and I recently added threads:

```
#include <thread>
```

Now my compilation is not working, even though it works for map/deque/vector/.... 
With the following error:

```
jni/common.h:24:10: fatal error: 'thread' file not found
#include <thread>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

This is my `Application.mk`:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-18
APP_CPPFLAGS := -Wall -frtti -fexceptions -fpermissive
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

APP_STL:=stlport_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_OPTIM := release
```

This is my `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE     := XXXX

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/XXXXX

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := ....

LOCAL_C_FLAGS   := -O3 -std=c++11
LOCAL_CXX_FLAGS := -O3 -std=c++11

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I am using NDK 10d.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Most likely your version of the compiler does not support c++11 threads. Otherwise, try adding -std=c++11 to the APP_CPPFLAGS list of definitions.

Comment: I added my Android.mk, also I am using clang. So it should support std::thread. Changing to GCC 4.9 or GCC 4.8 does not help either.

Comment: You can simply include `#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif ` in all of your header files in which you're facing this issue.  `__cplusplus` will be defined for any compilation unit that is being run through the C++ compiler. It works really well. :)

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I'll answer myself :)

Seems that `APP_STL:=stlport_static` does not support C++ threads. Changing to the `APP_STL:=gnustl_static` solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I want to add that I was using Android Studio, and it seems to ignore Application.mk file. I had to open build.gradle of my module and add `stl "gnustl_static"` to ndk block, so it looks like this: `defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "testlibrary"
            cFlags "-DANDROID_NDK -std=gnu++0x -fexceptions"
            ldLibs "log"
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }
    }`